# interface device name em1 to eth0 linux 14.04 lts

Tags: networking, interface

I Have installed Linux 14.04 lts. I am getting interface device name as em1 and eth0.I want to rename it as eth0 and eth1.

Answer (score 6):

Best way to achieve that what you are looking for:

First, uninstall the package `biosdevname`

```
sudo apt-get remove biosdevname
```

then run

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After the next boot, everything will work the good ol way.

Comment: This worked for me. That package `biosdevname` must have been included as part of a recent apt-get upgrade I performed.

Answer (score 1):

Edit /etc/default/grub and search for the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=””
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=””
```

Add biosdevname=0 to the 2 lines:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”biosdevname=0”
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”biosdevname=0”
```

Then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Finally reboot, after reboot you should find all rules persisted in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 there is no grub file at that location, its found in `/boot/grub/grub.conf`. The solution that worked for me was by @oler http://askubuntu.com/a/620678/

Comment: Do you need to set `biosdevname=0` on both LINUX_DEFAULT and LINUX? the resulting grub.cfg has two `biosdevname=0`. Althought that shouldn't be a problem, I think you should be able to set either of the lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit 70-persistent-net.rules

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

Locate in the file the hardware named em1 and replace with eth*

Save and reboot

Comment: I have added this content to /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules  SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:10:b5:f5:b7:31", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0". and then saved and rebooted as you said but it is not happening.

Comment: You don't have to add anything, you should replace the line were em* was with eth* . Here is a little tutorial http://www.upubuntu.com/2013/03/how-to-change-your-network-adapter-name.html