# Changing the interface adapter to eth0 Ubuntu 22.04 Server

Tags: networking, server

I am currently working on writing a cloud init file for ubuntu 22.04. I have encountered a problem that the network adapter is called differently on different systems.

This means that I cannot write a good Netplan config.
Does anyone have a tip on how I can rename the network adapter name to eth0 on the system using cloud init?

The goal is that I can use this cloud init file on different systems / hosts.

Alternatively, I would have to use a separate cloud init file for each system, which I would not want to do.

maybe someone can help me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [interface device name em1 to eth0 linux 14.04 lts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578650/interface-device-name-em1-to-eth0-linux-14-04-lts)

Comment: No, because /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules  is empty and the user was asking to add something. The linked tutorial is down.   /boot/grub/grub.conf is also empty and mybe something is chaned since 8 years